# HTML5 Canvas Drawing

Tags: html, canvas, createjs

I have a 100 (width) x 100 (Height) canvas arranged in a row and column of 5 x 6

it has a triangle drawn on them currently the canvas are arranged in such a way that every canvas overlaps each other. i want to add click on the triangle area

is there a way to bypass click to the underlying canvas when the click is in transparent area of the top canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EaselJS, you can use the `nextStage` property to pass CreateJS mouse interactions to canvases that are below one another in the DOM.

```
// Overlapping Canvases
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>

// Multiple Stages
stage1 = new createjs.Stage("canvas1"),
  stage2 = new createjs.Stage("canvas2");

// Mouse events on content in each stage
stage1child.on("click", handleClick);
stage2child.on("click", handleClick);

// Stage 2 is higher in the DOM, so it will receive the mouse events first.
// Pass them on to the lower canvas/stage
stage2.nextStage = stage1;
```

Here is more info:

- [nextStage documentation](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#property_nextStage)
- [TwoStages demo in GitHub](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/TwoStages.html)
- [TwoStages demo on createjs.com](http://www.createjs.com/demos/easeljs/twostages)

Comment: its not working only on touch devices. is there a way around

Comment: Have you enabled Touch on the stage?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't entirely understood your question, but if you just want for the click to register to the Canvas bellow the shape, then you need to disable the mouse interaction for the shape on top, like this:

`triangleShape.mouseEnabled = false;`

By doing so, any mouse events will be ignored for this shape and passed instead to the objects bellow it.